# Is there a way to decrease blurriness in video so that the text is readable?

Tags: video-editor, video-quality

I have a video of a lecture but the resolution is not great and I can't really read what's written on the blackboard. Is there a way to artificially increase the resolution or decrease blurriness? It doesn't have to be perfect, just so that I can read the text. Preferably in After effects since that's the one editor I have, but anything else will do as well.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the "Sharpen" effect, which increases contracts.